# Android Formatting Date

Tags: android, date-format

I need help with formatting date in Android. I have learned how to implement date like this `yyyy-MM-dd` but now I want like this `Dec 31, 1969`. How can I implement this dateFormat in Java?

Comment: why read the doc when you can ask the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf  = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

It will return the Date at your requested format!

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html